# Firebase authentication using custom ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a sign-in page where the user has to enter their own unique ID and password to log-in into my application. The unique ID should already exist within the firebase database. For example, the user has to insert their student ID and password via firebase authentication. Hope to get help from the community. Thanks.

*note I am a complete newbie in firebase and any mobile application development. Hope you guys can bear with me if I asked any basic question.

Comment: You either manually register all unique student ID into a `Student` node or allow students to have an option to proceed with registration.

Comment: @SharkesMonken Thank you for replying. So far I have manually added the student ID into a student table in the firebase real-time database. Is it possible to do this for firebase authentication or there is no reason for me to use f.authentication?

Comment: It's not practical best if you do it manually or provide a registration form

Comment: @AimanSalim did my answer make it a bit easier for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase database to store the unique ID and password and then retrieve it at the time of authentication.

You can have a structure like a main node `users` and a child node named `username` who has a child node named `password`. You can guess which node represents what, with their names.

First of all, for signing up in your app, you can offer users to choose their own ID and password, and you can check whether the same ID exists or not in your database with code similar to this:

```java
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
                    databaseReference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(n).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            else
                                writeNewUserNameIfNeeded(n);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

In above code `n` is the username the user have entered for themselves.

To write new username or password in the database, you can use a code similar to below:

```java
private void writeNewUserNameIfNeeded( final String username) {

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");

        usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                dataSnapshot.child("username").setValue(username);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

To check username and password or to grant login you can use a code similar to this:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("password").equals(pass))
                              // grant login access with these credentials


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What I understand is that I could do this via Real-time database firebase right? I have done by using the same method as same as yours wherein the login page the student ID will be compared to the ID in a real-time database. I've managed to log in and redirect to another page. Another question is by using this method, is there a way to do log in with session like in php?

Comment: This is the way to do using Firebase database, logging in with session like in php would I think is not entirely possible, but you should look in Google Docs to know more about it. If this answer helped you do it via Firebase, consider upvoting and marking it as correct. I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Comment: @AimanSalim, using this way in Firebase database is one of the best solution to what you want to achieve, as this not only gives you secure place to store your data, it also provides you with tons of options to work on, that can make things in your app a lot better.

Comment: I see. I will try to look into the login with session if it's possible with firebase. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Happy to help, Cheers! :)